# Symfony 2: Injecting logger for specific channel/handler to services

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

I am working on a Symfony 2 web app and I would like to inject a Monolog logger using a specific channel to a service:

The Config:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.root_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: error
            #channels: [!alert]
        alert:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.root_dir%/%kernel.environment%.alert.log
            level: info
            channels: [alert]
```

Service Config:

```
services:
    some_service:
     class: Some\Service
     arguments: [@logger]
     tags:
         - { name: monolog.logger, channel: alert }
```

The Service:

```
class SomeService {
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct($logger) {  
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->logger->info('Log this!');
    }
```

The prod.log file:

> [2016-03-28 11:25:47] alert.INFO: Log this!

**The Problem:** Although I specifically inject the logger using the `alert` channel, the message is handled by the `main` handler. Thus the messages are logged into the `prod.log` file instead of the `prod.alert.log` file.

When I leave the line `channels: [!alert]` as comment, the message is logged to `prod.log`. When I activate this line by removing the comment, the message is not logged at all (main handler ignores the channel correctly).

What have I to to, in order to use a specific handler to target a specific log file, mailer, etc? Messages to `alert` channel should be handled by the `alert` handler while all other handlers are ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use special service created for `Monolog` handler:

```
services:
    some_service:
        class: Namespace\Some\Service
        arguments: ["@monolog.logger.alert"]
```